# É possível atualizar uma guia com o react navigation sempre que eu acessa-lá?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

É possível atualizar uma guia com o react navigation sempre que eu acessa-lá?

por exemplo tenho 2 guias "Home" e "Settings"...

Se na guia home eu usar **navigation.navigator('Settings')**, a guia vai para **Settings**, porém se settings já tiver sido renderizada antes, ela não renderizará novamente.

tem como deixar no automático sempre que eu acessar settings, obrigar a guia a se renderizar novamente? ( atualizando estados, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Quando você abre a tela pela primeira vez, é executado o "componentDidMount" para montar a tela, se você continuar navegando, ele não vai ser mais executado.

Você pode mudar este comportamento verificando se a tela recebeu novas props, ou, adicionando um "listener" na hora de montar a tela pela primeira vez, para que sempre que ela receba o foco alguma programação seja executada. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class TabScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // Executar alguma ação
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove o listener ao desmontar
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}

export default withNavigation(TabScreen);
```

Aqui tem mais informações:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html